# How to use pattern and parse getJSON result and output?

Tags: javascript, getjson

could any one tell me why my patten code does not output any result?

added pattern code !

```
 matchingelements = code.match(/sid\=*(\d*)/ig); for(i=0;i<code.length;i++){
 document.write(matchingelements[i].replace('&sid=','').replace('sid=','')); 
}
```

this is full code?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com&callback=?',
function(data){  //$('#output').html(data.contents);

var code = data.contents;

document.myform.outputtext.value = code;

//pattern code
matchingelements = code.match(/sid\=*(\d*)/ig); for(i=0;i<code.length;i++){ 
document.write(matchingelements[i].replace('&sid=','').replace('sid=',''));
}

}); 

</script>

<form name="myform"> <td><textarea rows="7" cols="15" name="outputtext" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>    </form>
```

Comment: Does your javascript console log show any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i never used console log . i run this in firefox. how to use console log ?Aftern adding the pattern code i dont get no output and as soon as i remove it i get sitecontent in textbox!

Comment: It is the `console` tab in Firefox.  It tells you any time you have javascript errors.  You can also set breakpoints in your javascript and step through line by line to see what the value for your variables are.

Comment: you can't use `document.write` after page has loaded.

Comment: charlietfl so could you tell me how i can output the pattern result then ? should i stop outputing the sitecontent to textbox so i be able to document.write? i use the textbox to just make sure i get sitecontent!

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern appears to be invalid and I believe this is throwing an error. Try this pattern

`/(?:&|(\?))sid=[^&]*(\?(1)&|)?/ig`

All I've done is just escaped `\?` near `(?(1)...`

Comment: i updated the code. Now i get output after adding pattern code but i dont get any output for the pattern. It seems the program doesn't get enough time to do document.write. is there any solution for it?